# Remove characters from SUBSTRING_INDEX

Tags: mysql

I’m unserialize the data below

```
a:7:{s:12:"existingname";s:0:"";s:12:"originalname";s:50:"165074-mort-de-l-historien-jean-pierre-vernant.jpg";s:3:"alt";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"desc";s:0:"";s:6:"delete";b:0;s:6:"remove";b:0;}
```

using this quote

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,';',4),':',-1) AS bookimage 
  FROM jksid_flexicontent_fields_item_relations 
 WHERE jksid_flexicontent_fields_item_relations.field_id = 17  
   AND jksid_flexicontent_fields_item_relations.ite m_id = 13153
```

the result I have is

```
"165074-mort-de-l-historien-jean-pierre-vernant.jpg"
```

How can I remove the `"` symbols ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [replace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function. 
For excample: `REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,';',4),':',-1), '\"', '')`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,';',4),':',-1),'"','')  AS bookimage 
  FROM jksid_flexicontent_fields_item_relations 
 WHERE jksid_flexicontent_fields_item_relations.field_id = 17  
   AND jksid_flexicontent_fields_item_relations.ite m_id = 13153
```

Comment: `""` this should be single quotes

Comment: But its the same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31787541/4275342). Am I not right?

Comment: @MegaTron Both are same given answer same time not seed yours

Answer (score 0):

I think I stack again

When I copy it on the quote I’ve got syntax error

```
<?php
// get book image
mysql_select_db($database_fsd, $fsd);
$query_wrtbkimg = "
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,';',4),':',-1),'"','')  AS bookimage 
  FROM jksid_flexicontent_fields_item_relations 
 WHERE jksid_flexicontent_fields_item_relations.field_id = 17  
   AND jksid_flexicontent_fields_item_relations.ite m_id = 13153
";
$wrtbkimg = mysql_query($query_wrtbkimg, $fsd) or die(mysql_error());
$row_wrtbkimg = mysql_fetch_assoc($wrtbkimg);
$totalRows_wrtbkimg = mysql_num_rows($hwrtbkimg);
?>
```

Comment: This is not answer on your question, if you have a problem then edit your question or add comment to the answer

Comment: Try this: `REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,';',4),':',-1),'\"','')  AS bookimage`

Comment: Thanks a lot MegaTron and everybody